# in swing worker propertychange isn't being called

Tags: java, swing, swingworker, propertychangelistener

I have code which I have been using for years and this morning I noticed property change isn't being called when the task is done. I've got the swing worker set up as an inner class and I put a break point on the String properyName = evt..... and it never hits the break point.

```
void loadData() {
    work2 = new bkgdLoadData();
    work2.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            String propertyName = evt.getPropertyName();
            if( propertyName.equals("state")) {
                SwingWorker.StateValue state = (SwingWorker.StateValue) evt.getNewValue();
                if( state == SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE) {
                    work2 = null;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    work2.execute();
}
```

You can see that I set the object work2 to null when the task is finished and now it is no longer being set to null. In the class I added a done routine which it hits when the doinbackground is finished. What is puzzling me is why the property change listener isn't triggered. Something must have changed without my noticing.

```
protected class bkgdLoadData extends SwingWorker<Integer, Object> {
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground() {
        switch(bkgdMode) {
            case 0:
                doRead();
                break;

            case 1:
                doWrite();
                break;

            case 2:
                runRobot();
                break;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        int i=0;
        i++;
    }
}
```

The breakpoint at done is hit but no property change notice is delivered. (I put the done routine for the sole purpose of verifying that the swing worker knows that it is done.)

I looked at the documentation and I don't see that I have to manually fire off some sort of property change, so I am really, really stuck and would appreciate another pair of eyes to tell me what stupid mistake I am mistaking.

Thanks,
Ilan

Comment: You should read the Java Swing tutorial, the best source to solve your problems.

Comment: I can see the `PropertyChange` event being fired.  You need to make sure of a few extra things. 1- `doInBackground` is begin called (I know sounds stupid) and that `propertyChange` is/isn't.  For example.  Add some `System.out.println` statements to verify, at least, that the methods are begin called.  Also, `SwingWorker` uses a daemon thread, which means the JVM will exit even if the `SwingWorker` is still running

Comment: unrelated: a) the code in done does nothing: local field incremented ... b) please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: I know that I am incrementing a local variable. The only purpose was to have a line where I could put a break point. I put a break point on the return 0 of the doInBackground and another one in the done routine. I saw it hit the return in do in background and then it hit the done(). The only thing which didn't happen was to fire a property change. Likewise the very first thing I did was reread the documentation.

Comment: I did the only other thing I could think of - try it on a different machine. On my laptop it fires nicely. In my message I tried 2 break points at the return of doInBackground and done, as well as the one in the PropertyChange. As soon as it started in doInBackground I got a STARTED message. Being so concentrated on the DONE message I had forgotten about the STARTED. Neither I get on this machine, but my code is apparently correct. Now I just have to figure out what went wrong with this machine. Fun and games.....

Comment: See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Answer (score 0):

It turned out my Java was corrupted. Removing JDK 1.6 and reinstalling it from the repository wasn't good enough.

My links in Netbeans to 1.6 got damamged and I had to reinstall Netbeans as well (going over to 7.3.1 in the process). Netbeans would not recognize the repository JDK 1.6 as valid so I had to go to Oracle and get the original version. Netbeans recognized the original and the problem I reported above was no longer a problem.

I removed the void done() routine since it had no purpose other than a place to put a break point. The code as such is OK. Thanks for the help.