# which jdk is Netbeans using

Tags: ubuntu, netbeans, java

I asked a question as to why propertyChange wasn't being called in addPropertyChangeListener when a swing worker was working in the background. I thought something was wrong with my code. No one could help because the code was OK. I finally got confirmation when I ran it on my laptop where propertyChange was called.

So what could be wrong? Netbeans, Java, something gone bad on my Ubuntu? My gut feeling was that Netbeans shouldn't be able to influence something deep inside Java like propertyChange.

To test something I did a clean and build of the program and ran it outside Netbeans and there propertyChange is being called. Then I decided to look and see what JDK is available. Inside /usr/lib/jvm I have java-1.5.0-gcj-4.6 (ancient, no idea when I last used it), java-6-openjdk-i386 and java-7-openjdk-i386.

So the question was: which Java am I using? Maybe the Java has gone bad and that is the reason propertyChange isn't being called? I decided to print the Java version and test it. Inside Netbeans I got:

Sun Microsystems Inc.
http://java.sun.com/
1.6.0_27

In the clean and build version I got:

Oracle Corporation
http://java.oracle.com/
1.7.0_25

I suppose it could be that since Oracle bought Sun they changed the name on Java 7. I'll have to see if I can force the clean and build version to run Java 6. Inside Netbeans for that project the highest version available is 1.6.

I guess what I'd really like to hear is opinions on whether or not Netbeans could have a hand in the problem of propertyChange being called or not? Or is it only a question of which JDK I am using?

Thanks,
Ilan

Answer (score 1):

You can install the wanted JDK by :

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner"
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install sun-java6
```

You can also specify the JDK you want to use,

**On Linux :**

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7-netbeans-install-433844.html#linux

At the NetBeans IDE Installation page, do the following:
Specify the directory for the NetBeans IDE installation.
Accept the default JDK installation to use with the IDE or specify another JDK location.
Click Next.

**On windows :**

```
 - In the IDE, choose Tools > Java Platforms from the main menu.
 - Click Add Platform and specify the directory that contains the JDK (e.g. on Windows, this is 
 - the JDK installation directory, default is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0). 
 - The directory that contains the Java platform is marked with the Java Platform icon icon.
```

Hope it's helped

Comment: Thanks. I took your idea but not exactly as stated. My problem was: how do I know if it is really being updated? Maybe some other process is locking it? Finally inside of synaptic I managed to completely remove JDK6, but only after I killed another user who had locked it.

Comment: Once it was removed I could verify by looking at /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/bin that it was really removed. Then I reinstalled it. The problem is still there, i.e. if I run the build and clean program under the default java7, the propertyChange is called. Under java6 it isn't called. Why not is a mystery. I'll check it on my laptop to see what is happening there. Thanks for your comment and I did use your idea but I haven't gotten to the bottom of it yet.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041687/in-swing-worker-propertychange-isnt-being-called/18075572#18075572

Comment: In the end I found that the JDK 1.6 was corrupt. The repository version wasn't good enough so I went to Oracle. See the above link for details.

Comment: It was a long, hard road but yes it is finally working. I put the details in the above link. Let me say that I really appreciate your efforts to help. Those were dark days when Java wasn't working.